# SSIS OLE DB Destination not inserting accented characters

Tags: sql-server, encoding, ssis

I have the following table :

```
CREATE TABLE DI_Simulation 
(
    [city] nvarchar(255), 
    [profession] nvarchar(255) 
);
```

I load the data from an URL with a Script task where I created a class `Simulation` and added two string attributes. I then deserialize the downloaded JSON data and create output rows.

I specify that the output columns `city` and `profession` are of type `DT_WSTR` but the following characters [é,à,è,...] are always replaced...

I tried different collations on both columns but no changes were seen. I also tried forcing UTF8 conversion on the Script Task but that also didn't work.

Any suggestions ?

**EDIT**: I should also mention that I have other tables where the insertion is made correctly, but this one especially has this issue, which I'm thinking the Script Task has something to do with it.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;

// Convert json string to .net object using the old school JavaScriptSerializer class
string Uri = "https://....";
JavaScriptSerializer serialize = new JavaScriptSerializer
{
    MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue,
};

var simulation = serialize.Deserialize<Simulation[]>(DownloadJson(Uri));
```

**EDIT 2:**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(Url);
StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
var ags = streamreader.ReadToEnd();

/*System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\hhamdani\Desktop\Data Integration Objetcs\simulation_data.json",
ags,
System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));*/
var simulation = serialize.Deserialize<Simulation[]>(ags);
```

Instead of downloading with DownloadJson, I used streamreader to get the Json Data from the URL and forced the Encoding, when I save the data on a txt file it's good, but on the Database it's the same issue.

Comment: If the output columns are DT_WSTR then it sounds like there may be an encoding issue with JSON deserialization. Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71842511/edit) your question to show how you deserialize the JSON.

Comment: I would stash out the raw json to a file, something like `System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\temp\so_71842511.json", rawJson, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);` Does that json have the accented characters in it? Then repeat it for deserialized version of your data. If all good, then try a hard-coded version of the script like I show below with a hard coded example of the deserialized data.

Comment: @billinkc can you check my last edit.

Comment: `GetEncoding(1252)` is explicitly asking for Windows-1252 which is why you're losing the accented characters. Does `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` not work as a second argument in your StreamReader?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
Stream stream = client.OpenRead(Url);
StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
var ags = streamreader.ReadToEnd();
```

This did the job for me.
Thanks @billinkc

Answer (score 0):

Works fine from a script source component based on my reproduction

[image]

## Setup

### Table creation

A trivial table with two columns

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[SO_71842511] (
    [TestCase] int,
    [SomeText] nvarchar(50)
)
```

### SCR Do Unicode

Proof that we can inject unicode characters into the data flow task from a script source.

Define the Script Task as a Source. Add 2 columns to the output, one int, one DT_WSTR

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{
    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.SomeText = "e e plain";
        Output0Buffer.TestCase = 0;

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.SomeText = "é e forward";
        Output0Buffer.TestCase = 1;

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.SomeText = "à a back";
        Output0Buffer.TestCase = 2;

        Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        Output0Buffer.SomeText = "è e backward";
        Output0Buffer.TestCase = 3;
    }
}
```

### Results

[image]

Comment: So it's the deserializer then right ? although a flat file destination shows the characters just fine.

Comment: Maybe? The problem is that there's, potentially, a lot of moving parts. If a literal swap of the database destination to flat file yields accented characters, then the implication is that there's an issue with the destination - whether it's the table definition, something driver level, potentially database, etc, is hard to say without seeing the full reproduction

Comment: I downloaded the json data and stored it in a json file with the code line you provided, and in the characters are not well stored...